# django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'commons_smsmessages.sent_date' in 'field list'")

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm using mysql as a db and I'm getting a `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'commons_smsmessages.sent_date' in 'field list'")` when I add a field to the a pre-existing model. How do I fix it?

I tried `python manage.py makemigrations` and I've also tried deleting all the migration files and running `python manage.py makemigrations` but it doesn't seem to work.

This is the model I'm trying to update/add a field to:

```py
class SMSMessages(models.Model):
    sms_number_to = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    sms_content = models.CharField(max_length=160)
    sender_company = models.ForeignKey("SMSUser", on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="company_that_sent", limit_choices_to=1)
    sent_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "SMSMessages"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sender_company
```

The field I'm trying to add to the model is `sent_date`. But whenever I run `python manage.py makemigrations` I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 71, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 209, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 315, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 226, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'commons_smsmessages.sent_date' in 'field list'")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 399, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 584, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 577, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api/urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    path("", include('commons.urls')),
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/commons/urls.py", line 8, in <module>
    from commons.apiviews import TypeList, TypeDetail, SMSPriceList, SMSPriceDetail, SMSUserCreate, SMSUserUpdate
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/commons/apiviews.py", line 135, in <module>
    class SMSMessagesView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/commons/apiviews.py", line 142, in SMSMessagesView
    if not queryset:
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 278, in __bool__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 55, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1100, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 71, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 209, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 315, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/gadd/vscodeworkspace/sms.et/api.sms.et/api_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 226, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'commons_smsmessages.sent_date' in 'field list'")
```

What I was expecting is the python manage.py makemigrations to successfully run, update my db, and add the column to the model/table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've have solved right after posting the question. so turns out, God know why, if you use the model you're trying to update anywhere then django will throw the above error (again God knows why). So I commented out the code blocks that use the above model in the views.py, serializer.py, apiviews.py etc etc files and run `python manage.py makemigrations`, It worked.
I left here just in-case someone else runs into this problem.